# java.lang.AbstractMethodError in org.grails.testing.gorm.spock.DataTestSetupSpecInterceptor on Grails 4.0.11

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit, spock, grails-domain-class

I am facing an issue in the Spock framework. I have upgraded my application from Grails 3 to Grails 4. I have used Mixin in Grails 3 but since Grails 3.3, mixin is removed. Now I am using the Spock framework. I have created a sample Domain class and a Test Class but I am getting this error while running my test case:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.grails.testing.gorm.spock.DataTestSetupSpecInterceptor does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object getProperty(java.lang.String)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.

    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyTryThese(Closure.java:313)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyOwnerFirst(Closure.java:307)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getProperty(Closure.java:296)
    at org.grails.testing.gorm.spock.DataTestSetupSpecInterceptor.setupDataTestBeans_closure1(DataTestSetupSpecInterceptor.groovy:39)
    at org.grails.testing.gorm.spock.DataTestSetupSpecInterceptor.setupDataTestBeans_closure1(DataTestSetupSpecInterceptor.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:399)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:759)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:588)
    at org.grails.testing.GrailsUnitTest$Trait$Helper.defineBeans(GrailsUnitTest.groovy:97)
    at org.grails.testing.gorm.spock.DataTestSetupSpecInterceptor.setupDataTestBeans(DataTestSetupSpecInterceptor.groovy:38)
    at org.grails.testing.gorm.spock.DataTestSetupSpecInterceptor.configureDataTest(DataTestSetupSpecInterceptor.groovy:66)
    at org.grails.testing.gorm.spock.DataTestSetupSpecInterceptor.intercept(DataTestSetupSpecInterceptor.groovy:31)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:97)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Below are my Spec Class and Domain Class

```
class Person {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    static constraints = {
    }
}
class PersonSpec extends Specification implements DomainUnitTest<Person> {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
        expect:"fix me"
            true == false
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me out? TIA

Comment: I tried to recreate that problem at https://github.com/jeffbrown/zaidkhandomaintest and was unable to do so.  The test at https://github.com/jeffbrown/zaidkhandomaintest/blob/57e6421c3cd3c0f90fa403d33a8dea8da467a2d1/src/test/groovy/zaidkhandomaintest/PersonSpec.groovy fails because of `true == false`, not with an exception.  Does the exception manifest in your environment when you run the test in my repo?

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for trying it. I am still getting the exception. I am using IntelliJ Idea

Comment: I expect the problem is related to how your run config is created in IntelliJ.  Does the exception happen if you run `gradlew test` and leave IntelliJ out of it?

Comment: FYI, when I remove the DomainUnitTest implementation from PersonSpec, it worked fine. Any implementation related to spock framework causing this issue like implementing ControllerUniTest, DomainUnitTest, ServiceUnitTest etc

Comment: ./gradlew test also cauging issue

Comment: "./gradlew test also cauging issue" - i cannot reproduce that.  See https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/2f9c3da3ff6c62d3bf79c2d4d14596a6.  Which JDK are you using and what operating system?

Comment: Linux mint and JDK 11